# OpenGL Load Bitmap Routine Error

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, bitmap

My routine that loads a bitmap is doing it all wrong. When I'm texture mapping, the red pixels are converted to green and vice versa. 'LOAD' is the variable of a texture class that holds the bitmap data, 'tsLogSystemMessage' is just my error handling routine.
 Here's the code:

```
BMT.BMPwidth = -1; DWORD Bitread,SFP;
HANDLE BitFile = CreateFileA(imagepath,GENERIC_READ,NULL,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
if(BitFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
{ 
    tsLogSystemMessage(LOG_MSG_ERROR,"File %s cannot be opened or does not exist\n",imagepath);
    return(BMT); //continue with error operation
}
ReadFile(BitFile,&LOAD.BMPheader,54,&Bitread,NULL);
if((Bitread == 0) || (Bitread != 54))
{
    tsLogSystemMessage(LOG_MSG_ERROR,"ERROR: UNEXPECTED END OF FILE FOUND!!!%s\n",imagepath);
    return(BMT); //continue with error operation
}
if (LOAD.BMPheader[0]!='B' || LOAD.BMPheader[1]!='M' )//The first 2 bytes should be B and M
{    
    tsLogSystemMessage(LOG_MSG_ERROR,"ERROR: Incorrect Bitmap Format in file: %s\n",imagepath);
    return(BMT); //continue with error operation
} 
// Read ints from the byte array
LOAD.BMPdataPos    = *(int*)&(LOAD.BMPheader[0x0A]);
LOAD.BMPSize  = *(int*)&(LOAD.BMPheader[0x22]);
LOAD.BMPwidth      = *(int*)&(LOAD.BMPheader[0x12]);
LOAD.BMPheight     = *(int*)&(LOAD.BMPheader[0x16]);
// Some BMP files are misformatted, guess missing information
if (LOAD.BMPSize==0)    LOAD.BMPSize = LOAD.BMPwidth * LOAD.BMPheight *3; // 3 : one byte for each Red, Green and Blue component
if (LOAD.BMPdataPos==0)      LOAD.BMPdataPos=54;
// Create a buffer
LOAD.data = new unsigned char [LOAD.BMPSize]; // Read the actual data from the file into the buffer
SFP = SetFilePointer(BitFile,1,NULL,FILE_BEGIN); //Reading all data from the beginning of file
if(!SFP)//Can't read from beginning? Problem.
{
    tsLogSystemMessage(LOG_MSG_ERROR,"ERROR: Unable to complete read operation in file: %s\n",imagepath);
    return(BMT); //continue with error operation
}
else
{
    ReadFile(BitFile,LOAD.data,LOAD.BMPSize,&Bitread,NULL); //Read all data
    if((Bitread == 0) || (Bitread != LOAD.BMPSize))
    {
        tsLogSystemMessage(LOG_MSG_ERROR,"ERROR: UNEXPECTED END OF FILE FOUND!!!%s\n",imagepath);
        return(BMT); //continue with error operation
    }
} 
tsLogSystemMessage(LOG_MSG_REPORT,"Texture %s Opened Successfully....\n",imagepath);
CloseHandle(BitFile);
return(LOAD);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!!!!

Okay, And my glTexImage2d routine:
 PARTTEXDATA is the class variable for the returned class from the routine above, 'count' is a parameter passed of how much textures will be loaded.

```
    glGenTextures(count,TEXTURE_IDS);
    for(XP = 0;XP < count;XP++)
   {
    PARTTEXDATA = tsLoadBitmapFile(files[XP]);
    if(PARTTEXDATA.BMPdataPos != -1)
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,TEXTURE_IDS[XP]);
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB,PARTTEXDATA.BMPwidth,PARTTEXDATA.BMPheight, 0,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            PARTTEXDATA.data );
        free(PARTTEXDATA.data);
    }

    }
    for(tt = 0;tt < count; tt++) //This loop allows the ID's for the textures to be available for all other BITMAP_OPERATION classes in this project
    {
        TEXES[tt] = TEXTURE_IDS[tt];
    }
    return(1);
```

Comment: Show the code where you upload the texture to OpenGL. Most probably the format parameter of `glTexImage2D` is wrong (GL_RGB instead of GL_BGR).

Comment: I added the routine above.

Comment: Have you tried changing GL_RGB to GL_BGR?

Comment: BMP is a rather involved file format. Trying to write your own bitmap importer is destined to fail. At least one major vendor of graphics applications still does not write standards-compliant BMP files. Instead, let someone else do the heavy lifting for you. Use the [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx), for example. Your code has one glaring error: The size of a bitmap is the **stride** multiplied by the height multiplied by bpp. The stride is a multiple of four (this is what you're ignoring).

Comment: I avoid using bitmaps if possible for using as a texture either in OpenGL or DirectX. I use tga & png files! Due to the same reason that Iinspectable stated. If using TGA you will have to write your own file loader and store the contents into a custom structure. If using PNG the PGN Library works well and again you would need to store the contents into a custom structure. If you design the custom structure correctly you can read either file and upload it to a texture object, from there you can have OpenGL apply the texture to any object.

Comment: @FrancisCugler: There's not need for a 3rd party library. The Windows Imaging Component provides a [native PNG codec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg430027.aspx).

Comment: Okay. Thanks guys! I'll see what I can do.